# Two sample specific questions about books and tools

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Would be the following questions acceptable on Programmers site:

1. Few years ago book XYZ by AuthorSoAndSo was considered **the** book on ABC.  Is it still the case? Has it become outdated?
2. In job posts I often see a requirement to be proficient with SuchAndSuch type of applications.  What are the main concerns with these applications?  What kind of tooling should a programmer become intimately familiar with to claim such proficiency?

Are the above questions *specific* enough to survive?

Answer (score 2):

The first question *might* survive, but a lot depends on the specific book/technology. The really good books don't become outdated that fast, unless the technology is evolving very fast and/or a much better alternative has become available. On the other hand, if the technology has evolved and some books are available that are more up-to-date, but nothing to clearly replace the original book, then there is a real chance that it comes down to personal opinion if book XYZ is still the best. Such questions tend to be closed as ["primarily opinion based"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6491/).

The second question most likely won't survive. That question is seeking career advise and such questions are explicitly off-topic. See also ["Why was my question closed as off topic?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/)

Comment: What if the second question is worded differently : What tools are essential for this type of apps?  No career advice here.

Comment: @PM77-1: No, but then it is either a 'big list' question (too broad) or a request for recommendation (off topic).